# Unknown exception during ejb method invocation

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I create stress test to my swing app. swing app call remote EJB method which returns List of entities. I put remote method invocation in for loop and set max iteration to 5000 calls to server, after that I run 2 clients but after some number of calls, server throws exception

Application server GlassFish 3.01 b22

```
    WARNING: "IOP00010202: (UNKNOWN) Unknown user exception thrown by the server - exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException; message: null"
org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.runtimeexception(ORBUtilSystemException.java:11015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.convertThrowableToSystemException(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2075)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2025)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleThrowableDuringServerDispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1978)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:289)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1841)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1695)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1078)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:221)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:797)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:561)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2558)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:492)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:528)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:573)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:760)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:716)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:932)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:917)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1044)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1057)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:774)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:681)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:887)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:959)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:718)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:932)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:917)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1044)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1057)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:760)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:709)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:501)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:322)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:760)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:716)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:932)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:917)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1044)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1057)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:774)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:681)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:887)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:959)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:718)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:932)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:917)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1044)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:1057)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:774)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:681)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.write(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:394)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.writeResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:490)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:682)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:216)
    ... 9 more
```

EJB method returns Folders Entity

```
@Entity

    public class Folders implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    private List<Folders> chileFolders = new ArrayList<Folders>();

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FOLDER_GROUP_ID", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private long parentFolderId;

    //other attributes of folder entity

    public Folders() {
    }

public List<Folders> getChildes() {
    return chileFolders;
}

public void setChildes(List<Folders> foldersList) {
    this.chileFolders = foldersList;
}

/**
 * removes all elements from transiant field {@link #chileFolders}
 */
public void removeAllChildes() {
    chileFolders.removeAll(chileFolders);
    }
}
```

In EJB method I create recursion select of Folder Entities With it childes. Folder entity in database
mapped to its parent entity by parentFolderId object.

```
@Stateless 
    public class FolderManager implements FolderManagerRemote {
    //remote ejb method
    @Override
    public Folders findRootFolder() throws RecordDoNotExistException {
        //root folder
        Folders tempRoot = new Folders();
        tempRoot.setId((long) 1);
        tempRoot.setParentFolderId(0);
        recursionSelectFromRootFolder(tempRoot);
        return tempRoot;
    }
    //recursion select
    private void recursionSelectFromRootFolder(Folders root) {
        List<Folders> folderList = getChildes(root);
        //maybe this is cause of exception ????? removeAllChildes()
        root.removeAllChildes();
        for (Iterator iterator = folderList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Folders folders = (Folders) iterator.next();
            List<Folders> childesOfRoot = root.getChildes();
            childesOfRoot.add(folders);
            root.setChildes(childesOfRoot);
            if (hasChildes(folders)) {
                recursionSelectFromRootFolder(folders);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

I use removeAllChildes() method from Folders Entity to remove previously selected childs for Folder

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that a List of Lists is being **serialized and modified** at the same time by two different threads.  The serialization is due to the remote EJB call, but to say where the modification is, we'd need to see some code

Based on the fact that you have two of these in your stack trace

```
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
```

Do you have a List of Lists as a member of your EJB class?  Are you modifying it in the EJB call as well as returning it?

Comment: I have one method in entity which removes List elemets from transiant field. Invocation of this method occur in ejb method.

Comment: I think the @Transient annotation is different than the transient keyword.  Try 'private transient List<Folders> chileFolders...'